# How to clean a placeholder value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, placeholder

Look a this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Fill this" value="">
```

How can I clean the `placeholder` value when I focus the textbox?

I mean, before the user start to write anything I want to use the jQuery to clean the `placeholder` text -> `fill this`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can change the placeholder attribute with `attr()`, and set it to nothing on `focus`, and back again on `blur`

```
$('#name').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    var placeholder = e.type == 'focus' ? '' : 'Fill this';
    $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mk5pB/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#name').attr("placeholder", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the Browser did it per default. That's what the placeholder Attribute is designed for.

But if you want to change this Attribute with jQuery I would try following code normally used to change every existing Attribute:

```
$('#name').attr('placeholder', '');
```